# Place a custom block inside admin area

Tags: blocks, theming

How is it possible to place a custom block inside the admin area? (e.g. in a node edit form)? I tried with page restriction but with no success. How can I see the block regions of the admin theme (seven)?

Comment: Assuming the Seven theme, the node edit form is wholly in the content region. You'll need to create a new (sub-)theme which divides the page template up into the regions you require, then you can use the block layout page for this. Alternatively you can implement `hook_form_alter()`, programatically build the view for a block, and add it to the `$form` in an appropriate place.

Answer (score 1):

You can just go to "Structure > block layout" from the admin bar. This will default to your current default theme but along the top of that page it will list out all other active themes and "Seven" will be one of them

Click that and the block listing will now be for the Seven theme and you can add/remove blocks like you can normally except it will now be for the Seven theme

You wouldn't be able to place a block midway through the form but you could add a block above/below the form

Comment: Thanks for your help, but for some reason the "seven" theme is not appearing on top. The only one that is visible, it is the frontend theme

Comment: Not sure why that might be, maybe something on your code is messing about with it. This is the url to view the seven blocks /admin/structure/block/list/seven